# Is this going to be a huge If/Then statement?

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement

I am trying to implement a series of notifications based on radio button options the user selects.  The notifications date and time will set depending on both radio button options and the user selected date.

for example the user selects Option 1, 2 and 3 along with Jan 1st 2017 and 12 notifications are set every couple of days/weeks depending on said options.

Before I get too far into this, am I just looking at a complex if then statement to set these notifications or am i missing another solution?

Comment: It'd be better if you can use a switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your if-else statements get too long you might be needing a switch statement instead. You said there are twelve notification options so a switch could do this just fine.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Remember to separate each option in a modular fashion using different classes, or methods so that you just have to call each block of code.

Comment: I played with swtiches a little and I think i have a light grasp on them.  I am trying to use radio buttons as my user selection interface. I gather that the switch executes upon selection of the radio button?  How would i go about waiting to run the switch until the user clicks a "set options" button?

Comment: my bad, i wasn't looking at my code properly.  Thank you, switch statements seem to be much easier than if/else for my purposes.  Ill mark you correct, but i dont know if i have enough rep yet for it to show.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of switcing or if/else can also be a symptom of you trying to express intrinsically polymorphic code. You are essentially replicating the vtable the compiler would do for you. Following separating business logic from view (rendering) logic -- ie some form of MVC -- you could associate a subclass with each radio button to which the button delegates the logic when it is pressed (btw you might not necessarily need separate subclasses). The controller of each radio button may have a reference to some other object which stores the final frequency of days/hours/minutes, etc for each to call the alarm. So as each radio button is pressed, it delegates to its controller which in turn interprets the value of the radio button and in turn calls into the alarm controller, incrementing / decrementing some value using some appropriate API.

I know it might sound like over-engineering but it is quite simple to set up and it is likely that you will minimally need that alarm controller for other details (which also makes it a lot easier to test; you definitely do not want to shove business logic in your views (activities) as it makes testing a nightmare). So if you wish to simplify this, you could forego each button's individual controller and instead have each button directly invoke the alarm controller API if you prefer to update it.

Comment: your answer may just be correct, but it is way above my head at this point.  Thank you for taking your time to answer, perhaps I can use this at a later date when i understand more than half of what you said.